# Pandas shuffle rows at a certain level

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` using a `MultiIndex` on the rows:

```
index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(itertools.product(range(3), range(3))))
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(9,3), index=index, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

            A         B         C
0 0  2.400417  0.698638  1.231540
  1 -0.023154 -2.110450  0.774964
  2 -1.282392 -0.062794  1.471655
1 0 -1.081853  0.261876 -1.771075
  1 -2.013747 -0.377957 -0.393802
  2  1.711172 -0.552468  1.018727
2 0  0.155821 -0.222691  0.496586
  1  0.563638 -0.756709  1.050212
  2 -1.446159 -0.891549  0.256695
```

I would like to shuffle this DataFrame on the first level of the index, so a possible result would be:

```
            A         B         C
1 0 -1.081853  0.261876 -1.771075
  1 -2.013747 -0.377957 -0.393802
  2  1.711172 -0.552468  1.018727
0 0  2.400417  0.698638  1.231540
  1 -0.023154 -2.110450  0.774964
  2 -1.282392 -0.062794  1.471655
2 0  0.155821 -0.222691  0.496586
  1  0.563638 -0.756709  1.050212
  2 -1.446159 -0.891549  0.256695
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `reindex` method can accomplish this when passed a reordered array of tuples matching the desired order.  At which point, reordering can be done as best fits your problem.  For example:

```
In [38]: df
Out[38]: 
            A         B         C
0 0 -1.725337  0.111493  0.178294
  1 -1.809003 -0.614219 -0.931909
  2  0.621427 -0.186233  0.254727
1 0 -1.322863  1.242415  1.375579
  1  0.249738 -1.280204  0.356491
  2 -0.743671  0.325841 -0.167772
2 0 -0.070937  0.401172 -1.790801
  1  1.433794  2.257198  1.848435
  2 -1.021557 -1.054363 -1.485536

In [39]: neworder = [1, 0, 2]

In [41]: newindex = sorted(df.index, key=lambda x: neworder.index(x[0]))

In [42]: newindex
Out[42]: 
[(1L, 0L),
 (1L, 1L),
 (1L, 2L),
 (0L, 0L),
 (0L, 1L),
 (0L, 2L),
 (2L, 0L),
 (2L, 1L),
 (2L, 2L)]

In [43]: df.reindex(newindex)
Out[43]: 
            A         B         C
1 0 -1.322863  1.242415  1.375579
  1  0.249738 -1.280204  0.356491
  2 -0.743671  0.325841 -0.167772
0 0 -1.725337  0.111493  0.178294
  1 -1.809003 -0.614219 -0.931909
  2  0.621427 -0.186233  0.254727
2 0 -0.070937  0.401172 -1.790801
  1  1.433794  2.257198  1.848435
  2 -1.021557 -1.054363 -1.485536
```

Comment: That is a very elegant solution. I ended up vectorizing the sort like this: `newindex = df.index[ np.argsort(neworder[df.index.labels[0]]) ]`

Comment: kudos for vectorizing!  You have up'd my Numpy-fu.  One point: since ``np.sort``/``np.argsort`` use the 'quicksort' algorithm by default, which is not guaranteed stable, it's not equivalent to using Python's sorted function, which is guaranteed stable.  Sorting in your solution can made stable with argument ``kind='heapsort'`` though.

Comment: @Garrett by the docs of numpy (v 1.7.1) `'heapsort'` is not stable. However `'mergesort'` is said to be stable. Why do you recommend one over the other?

Comment: In general, it shouldn't matter, I was just pointing out a difference between the two approaches.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that `heapsort` is not stable!

Comment: The accepted solution is not working for me, I am getting an IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable error. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using?  The solution still works for me on pandas 0.14.1 and current master (0.15)

Answer (score 1):

A simple, concise solution is

```py
icol = df.index.levels[k]
df.loc[icol[permutation]]
```

which works for the outermost level. To get a general level, either use [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) or [`IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html)

Full MWE:

```py
import pandas
from io import StringIO

table = """   
i j  A         B         C
0 0  2.400417  0.698638  1.231540
  1 -0.023154 -2.110450  0.774964
  2 -1.282392 -0.062794  1.471655
1 0 -1.081853  0.261876 -1.771075
  1 -2.013747 -0.377957 -0.393802
  2  1.711172 -0.552468  1.018727
2 0  0.155821 -0.222691  0.496586
  1  0.563638 -0.756709  1.050212
  2 -1.446159 -0.891549  0.256695
"""

df = pandas.read_fwf(StringIO(table), dtype={"i":"UInt8", "j":"UInt8"})
df = df.ffill().set_index(["i", "j"])

i, j = df.index.levels
idx = pandas.IndexSlice
perm = [2,0,1]
df.loc[i[perm]]
```

Returns

```
            A         B         C
i j                              
2 0  0.155821 -0.222691  0.496586
  1  0.563638 -0.756709  1.050212
  2 -1.446159 -0.891549  0.256695
0 0  2.400417  0.698638  1.231540
  1 -0.023154 -2.110450  0.774964
  2 -1.282392 -0.062794  1.471655
1 0 -1.081853  0.261876 -1.771075
  1 -2.013747 -0.377957 -0.393802
  2  1.711172 -0.552468  1.018727
```

And `df.loc[idx[i, j[perm]], :]` gives

```
            A         B         C
i j                              
0 2 -1.282392 -0.062794  1.471655
  0  2.400417  0.698638  1.231540
  1 -0.023154 -2.110450  0.774964
1 2  1.711172 -0.552468  1.018727
  0 -1.081853  0.261876 -1.771075
  1 -2.013747 -0.377957 -0.393802
2 2 -1.446159 -0.891549  0.256695
  0  0.155821 -0.222691  0.496586
  1  0.563638 -0.756709  1.050212
```

But be careful! Although `df.loc[idx[i[perm], :], :]` and `df.loc[idx[i[[perm]], j], :]` give the same result, the above `df.loc[idx[i, j[perm]], :]` returns something different than the (maybe) unexpected result from `df.loc[idx[:, j[perm]], :]`:

```
            A         B         C
i j                              
0 2 -1.282392 -0.062794  1.471655
1 2  1.711172 -0.552468  1.018727
2 2 -1.446159 -0.891549  0.256695
0 0  2.400417  0.698638  1.231540
1 0 -1.081853  0.261876 -1.771075
2 0  0.155821 -0.222691  0.496586
0 1 -0.023154 -2.110450  0.774964
1 1 -2.013747 -0.377957 -0.393802
2 1  0.563638 -0.756709  1.050212
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if the following worked, [but no](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index):

```
df.ix[[1, 0, 2]]
```

The following is more of a workaround. Maybe there is a better way but I couldn't figure out any. This merely creates a list of `DataFrame` 'slices' in the correct order and concatenates them with [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects).

```
In : df
Out:
            A         B         C
0 0  1.202098 -0.031121  1.417629
  1 -0.895862  0.697531 -0.572411
  2  1.179101 -0.008602  1.583385
1 0  1.969477 -0.968004 -0.567695
  1 -1.504443 -0.002264 -0.413091
  2 -1.412457  0.310518  0.267475
2 0 -0.385933 -0.471800 -0.598141
  1 -0.105032  0.443437 -0.615566
  2 -1.035326 -0.282289 -0.042762

In : shuffled = [2,0,1]

In : df2 = pandas.concat([df.ix[i:i] for i in shuffled])

In : df2
Out:
            A         B         C
2 0 -0.385933 -0.471800 -0.598141
  1 -0.105032  0.443437 -0.615566
  2 -1.035326 -0.282289 -0.042762
0 0  1.202098 -0.031121  1.417629
  1 -0.895862  0.697531 -0.572411
  2  1.179101 -0.008602  1.583385
1 0  1.969477 -0.968004 -0.567695
  1 -1.504443 -0.002264 -0.413091
  2 -1.412457  0.310518  0.267475
```

Comment: why does this not work? idx =IndexSlice    df.loc[idx[shuffled,:]]