# iterating randomly through groups in python data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame named 'lattice' with an attribute 'level'

```
g_lattice=lattice.groupby('level')
```

How do I  traverse the groups in g_lattice randomly based on the level.

Comment: Duplicate question, though I like Jeff's solution better than any I see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445549/pandas-shuffle-rows-at-a-certain-level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [22]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar'] * 3,
                            'B': rand.randn(6),
                            'C': rand.randint(0, 20, 6)})

In [23]: groups = list(df.groupby('A'))

In [24]: random.shuffle(groups)

In [25]: for g, grp in groups:
    print grp
   ....:     
     A         B   C
0  foo  0.900856   4
2  foo -0.122890  19
4  foo -0.267888   8
     A         B  C
1  bar -0.683728  5
3  bar -0.935769  6
5  bar  0.530355  0
```

Comment: How can we get all the rows belonging to a particular group as a separate data frame?

Comment: well the grp that I am printing IS a frame, your could also do groups.get_group('bar')